# Type 2 errors with Bayesian models (brms)

Tags: modeling, bayesian, stan, significance, brms

Can anyone explain why the following model comes out as significant? I'm comparing one distribution with an exact copy of itself, but have tweaked the priors just right to get significance. I'm not sure why this can happen.

```
library(brms)
library(bayestestR)

# Create distribution
x <- rnorm(n = 6000, mean = 10, sd = 3.14)

# Copy it over two conditions
df1 <- data.frame(val = x, cond = "yes")
df2 <- data.frame(val = x, cond = "no")

# Join into one dataframe
df <- rbind(df1,df2)

# Set up priors
ipriors <- c(
  prior(normal(0, 20), class = Intercept),
  prior(normal(500, 3), class = b, coef="condyes"),
  prior(normal(0, 5), class = sigma)
)

# Fit model
m <- brm(val ~ cond,  data=df, family = gaussian(), prior = ipriors)

summary(m)

dat <- as.data.frame(m)
hypothesis(dat,"b_condyes > 0")
```

This yields a highly significant difference:

```
Hypothesis Tests for class :
       Hypothesis Estimate Est.Error CI.Lower CI.Upper Evid.Ratio Post.Prob Star
1 (b_condyes) > 0     0.18      0.06     0.09     0.27    1332.33         1    *
```

I expected Bayesian models to be resistant to Type II errors.

A posterior predictive check looks good to me:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQVeh.png)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you have a very strong prior which suggests an effect with a normal(500,3). You would need a lot of evidence to overcome this. I would suggest to center the prior for the condition such as normal(0,3) or use a student t distribution.

For normal(0,3):

`Hypothesis Tests for class : Hypothesis Estimate Est.Error CI.Lower CI.Upper Evid.Ratio Post.Prob Star 1 (b_condyes) > 0        0      0.06     -0.1     0.09       0.98       0.5`

Also I don't think people would claim that there are no Type II errors in a Bayesian framework when using hypothesis testing.

Comment: Thank you for engaging! Yes, with the prior being so extreme, the model is going to ignore the actual data. But it fits the actual data very well, as per a predictive posterior check. If you run 
pp_check(m, ndraws = 100)
you see that the model predicts the data perfectly. So I guess one could reframe my original question: if the pp_check still fits to the data quite well, how can I detect cases where I've selected priors that are too narrow?

Comment: I guess you are still in a situation where you are close to 0 and the posterior wouldn't look much different overall except being skewed away from zero. You pretty much have part of the "real" distribution but ignore the other possibilities. I would generally start with prior-predictive checks and use a grouped output. Is the output of the priors reasonable? Do I force the result etc. ? Also something you might want is performing a sensitivity analysis. There are. Some packages available which can do this with PSIS and brms.